# Непонятный объект в GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

[image]

Добрый день, начал знакомиться с GitLab, и после каких-то действий в файловой структуре проекте возникла строка "name@8c498841" (ниже прилагается картинка), ни на что не реагирует. Что это такое понять не могу, может кто подскажет? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Это **субмодуль** — отдельная директория, в которой находится другой репозиторий Git со своей историей изменений.

Коммит, который выбран в субмодуле, сохраняется в основном репозитории. Это позволяет версионировать зависимости. Разным коммитам основного репозитория могут соответствовать разные коммиты субмодуля.

В данном случае это директория anagrams, а в ней — некий репозиторий на коммите 8c498841.